# Preseeding a Debian Jessie doesn't yield a default gateway

Tags: debian, preseed, cobbler

I used this in the .seed file:

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth0
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string fj4.testnet
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 10.201.0.34
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.0.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 10.201.0.1
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 10.206.0.11
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

which I use (adapted, with cobbler) and the installed system does have the correct ip address and netmask, but no gateway directive in the /etc/network/interfaces file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I thought that the problem was with the preseed file, but it really is with cobbler, whose "preseed_late_default" script overwrites /etc/network/interfaces without telling anyone.